# CSS Relative (to what?) position

Tags: css

I am making a website, it has just few lines and I just made its structure to see how it will look, and till now I thought I understand what means "Relative" position in CSS.
Here is my HTML and CSS code. If you take a look at CSS you will see in **#about div**

```
position: relative;
top: 13%;
```

In **#portfolio**

```
position: relative;
top: 0;
```

but its not on top of **#wrap div**. If I change its position to **absolute** it will be on top. So my question is: #portfolio div is relative to what? I thought It should be relative to wrap I think and it should change its top position relatively to wrap.
(Sorry about formatting of this post if you will be so nice to format it better it will be just great, i tried but it was horrible)

[Link to HTML and CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/NEgVk/)

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck In fact, not.

Comment: That is wrong @KrisHollenbeck, it is relative to its own normal position. http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-CSS2-19980512/visuren.html#relative-positioning

Comment: [A nice video illustration from Chris Coyier](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/110-quick-overview-of-css-position-values/). Please first learn what certain properties do, and complain only if they do not do what they are supposed to.

Comment: @bažmegakapa Ok i will take a look at that, I was just confused that It is not working as i thought it should work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`position: relative;` causes the item to be positioned relative to where it *would be* if you did not specify that option. The item still takes up the same 'space' as it would have, but may be moved. This does not have anything to do with positioning it within its parent.

For instance:

```
position: relative;
top: 5px;
```

Will cause the item to be moved 5 pixels down from where it *would otherwise be*.

```
position: relative;
top: -5px;
```

Would cause it to move 5 pixels up from where it would otherwise be.

Also note that it's possible to cause the object to overlap others or be moved outside of its parent by using this, depending on how much you offset it.

Comment: So which option is more "adaptable" if I want to make that site look same on more PCs with other resolutions? Change its position to absolute or use top: minus some pixels?

Comment: @MartinŠvoňava I don't think 'adaptable' is your issue, here; relative and absolute do very different things; It sounds to me like you probably need absolute, for your case (because you don't want an 'empty' space left where the relative positioned item would be. absolute positioned items have their original placement location 'collapsed', as if they did not exist at all.

Answer (score 0):

A relative positioned element is positioned relative to its normal position.

So if you have HTML like this:

```
<div style="height: 30px; padding: 0px; margin 0px;">Content</div>
<div style="height: 30px; padding: 0px; margin 0px; position:relative; top: -30px">Overlapping Content</div>
```

The second div would eclipse the first div in that it would be shifted up 30 px from where it would normally be positioned.

Honestly, relative positioning is rarely used with an actual top/bottom/left/right value in most web design.  Most use `position: relative` simply on a container element which will enclose absolute positioned elements.

Answer (score 0):

The css property `position:relative` positions the element normally in the flow, and then adds the values of `top, left, right` and `bottom`.

See [CSS position on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position).

In your case, `#about` and `#portfolio` are positionned using `position:relative;`.

`#about` takes up 23% of `#wrap`, so the top of `#portfolio` will have its initial position at 23% of `#wrap`.

Then, you change `#about` position with `top:13%` so it goes down to 13%, but you set `top:0;` for `#portfolio`, so it stays at 23%.

If you want your div to be positionned inside `#wrap`, you need to set `position:absolute;`. They will then be positionned relative to their closest positioned ancestor (here `#content`) or to the containing block.

Answer (score -1):

portfolio is relative to "content", that means everything you put into your "content" div  will be inheriting his features..